# Explain the Commons Lang code inside of synchronized()?

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm trying to to rewrite a piece of code from JakartaCommons-lang since we have a package that needs to have as few dependencies as possible

```
static void unregister(Object value) {
    Set registry = getRegistry();
    if (registry != null) {
        registry.remove(new IDKey(value));
        synchronized(class$org$apache$commons$lang$builder$HashCodeBuilder == null ? (class$org$apache$commons$lang$builder$HashCodeBuilder = class$("org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder")) : class$org$apache$commons$lang$builder$HashCodeBuilder) {
            registry = getRegistry();
            if (registry != null && registry.isEmpty()) {
                REGISTRY.set((Object)null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the code inside of synchronized()? Specifically all the '$'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is a valid identifier character, so it's just part of the name.

Note that use of `$` is discouraged. The Java Language Specification, section [3.8. Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says:

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters `A-Z` (`\u0041-\u005a`), and `a-z` (`\u0061-\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`) and underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`). **The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.** The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword.

Would it be more readable to you if it has used `_` instead?

```
synchronized (class_org_apache_commons_lang_builder_HashCodeBuilder == null ? (class_org_apache_commons_lang_builder_HashCodeBuilder = class_("org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder")) : class_org_apache_commons_lang_builder_HashCodeBuilder) {
    ...
}
```

or a shorter name?

```
synchronized (builderClass == null ? (builderClass = getClass("org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder")) : builderClass) {
    ...
}
```